# OpenCV 3.0.0 build error, make: *** [all] Error 2

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I got this error while building open-CV 3.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04,

```
[ 86%] Built target opencv_java
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you post the full output?